# Clarification as to the adverb discerningly

Tags: adverbs

Nowadays people don't need to be able to write beautifully by hand.
They don't need to be able to multiply numbers in their heads.
In fact, they need to be able to read discerningly.

It would be appreciated if anyone possibly would throw a light on the concept of this sentence, especially the adverb discerningly.

Cheers,
 Nima

Comment: Could you provide a broader context?

Comment: I'm thinking that the author was probably trying to make a point that those people (us?) don't need to be able to read in the near future. It sounds like they were speculating that sooner or later, reading would be meaningless. Just like keyboards have made handwriting meaningless, and calculators have made multiplication (in our heads) meaningless.

Comment: The adverb may have two meanings here. "Read discerningly" may mean skimming - choosing what to read thoroughly and what to skip as unnecessary fluff, selectively picking information, or alternatively, read critically, not accepting everything we read for a fact, since the common access to media for everyone makes falsehoods, misinterpretations and baseless gossip abundant, so you must discern which information is "good".

Answer (score 1):

Google gives the following definitions for *discern*:

> perceive or recognize (something).
>
> distinguish (someone or something) with difficulty by sight or with the other senses.

The sentence is probably talking about the effects of the modern information age upon us.  To me, it is saying it is not as useful anymore to develop things like the mechanics of writing or rote memorization of information - computers today can print text and compute math faster than human beings - but far more useful to be able to *discern* or find/recognize/distinguish the information you need or is relevant from the overload of available information.